# Customizing output of Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-model-serializers

So I wanted to use the new `[ActiveModel::Serializer][1]` that has been recently added to rails.

If I write my serializer like this:

```
class PatientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :patient_money, :doctor_name

  def doctor_name
    object.doctor.name
  end
end
```

The JSON I get is like this:

```
[
// HERE.... 
   {
      "patient_money":"40.0",
      "doctor_name":"Ostad"
   },
   {
      "patient_money":"30.0",
      "doctor_name":"Oz"
   },
   {
      "patient_money":"20.0",
      "doctor_name":"Phil"
   }
]
```

Which is very close to what I want BUT at the place I put that "`HERE`" comment above, I want one more wrapping layer of JSON so I could say for example `my_results` and then that wraps those three JSON results around it like an array, just like when we create a new element in JBuilder when we say `json.my_results`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it.
In the **controller** that is sending a `respond_with(@blah)` I should pass a root element and name it whatever I like for example:

```
respond_with(@blah, root: 'my_results')
```